# Software uses Google - Speech To Text API - Want to Buy

Tags: open-source

I want to buy a software or any open source if available which can be installed on machine and uses Google Cloud Vision API to convert speech to text.

I want to convert my audio files to text.

Please advise which software uses the Google Cloud Vision API

My budget would be less than or equal to 100$.

Comment: Welcome. Do you have a budget in mind? And an operating system on which this app should run?  The more info you give us, the better that we can help you, as explain in [ask]

Comment: my budget would be less than or equal to 100$.

Comment: I added that to your question. As explained in [ask], the more detail you give us, the better that we can help you. For instance, we no know not to recommend something costing $1,000.  Welcome aboard! I hope that you get a satisfactory answer :-)